# How to convert picture from byte to base64 in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I upload picture on profile picture.
It can't show the image but in database is found
I want to know if my code is right to convert the byte Image in database to base64 or no

This is my code :
Model class is

```
 public class Registerpage : IdentityUser
 {
     
    public required string FirstName { get; set; }
    public required string LastName { get; set; }
     public byte[]? ProfilePicture { get; set; }
 }
```

Input model

```
 public class InputModel
 {
    
     [Phone]
     [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
     public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

     [Display(Name ="First Name")]
     public  string FirstName { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     public byte[] ProfilePicture { get; set; }

 }

 private async Task LoadAsync(Registerpage user)
  {
     var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
     var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

     Username = userName;

     Input = new InputModel
     {
         PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
         FirstName=user.FirstName,
         LastName=user.LastName,
         ProfilePicture=user.ProfilePicture,
     };
 }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await LoadAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }
        
      
        if(Request.Form.Files.Count>0)
        {
            var formfile=Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await formfile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                user.ProfilePicture= stream.ToArray();
            }
            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        }
     //Other data 
        await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
        StatusMessage = "Your profile has been updated";
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
}
```

The Index view page is

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Profile";
    ViewData["ActivePage"] = ManageNavPages.Index;
}
@{
    string base64tostring = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Input.ProfilePicture, 0, Model.Input.ProfilePicture.Length);
    var Imagesrc = string.Format( "data:Image/*;base64" + base64tostring);
}
<h3>@ViewData["Title"]</h3>
<partial name="_StatusMessage" for="StatusMessage" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form id="profile-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger" role="alert"></div>
        @*previous code*@
            <div >
                <input type="file" asp-for="Input.ProfilePicture" onchange="loadfile(event)" class="form-control"/>
                <br />
                @if(Model.Input.ProfilePicture!=null)
                {
                    <img id="Image" alt="Profile Picture" 
                        src="@Imagesrc"
                        style="width:200px;height:200px" />

                }
                else
                {
                    <img src="~/Images/Profile Picture.jpg" style="width:200px;height:200px" />

                }
            </div>
         <br />
            <button id="update-profile-button" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    <script>
        var loadfile = function (event) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function () {
                var Image = document.getElementById('Image');
                Image.src = reader.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
    </script>
}
```

This the picture is explain what happen in my Project.
[MY Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LzKM.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the `,` after `base64` in the following code:

```
var Imagesrc = string.Format("data:Image/*;base64," + base64tostring);
```